# WWW request send always en-US in Accept-Language

Tags: unity-game-engine

Do you know how to send the right Accept-Language in Unity?
I use the class WWW to perform the requests but it always send "en-US".

Thanks for your answers !

Here is my code:

```
// Header request
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// My server code need this
headers.Add ("Accept", "application/json");

WWW w = new WWW (MY_URL, null, headers);
yield return w;
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the same you did for "Accept"? I mean `headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-gb");` for example.

Comment: I would like to do that, but I don't know how to retrieve the value "en-gb" for each user. Do you know how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html)

This allows you to adjust the header content.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer ! It may be a good idea but I still need to retrieve the correct current culture before passing it to WWWForm. Do you know how to retrieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Dictionary with the language of the operating system as a key and the string format for the field Accept-Language as a value. Then you can get the language of the user's operating system using  `Application.systemLanguage`. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-systemLanguage.html

`Dictionary<string, string> language = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// add all other languages here
language.Add("English", "en-gb");
headers.Add("Accept-Language", language[Application.systemLanguage]);`

List of languages returned: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemLanguage.html

Also remember that this solves only the language part, with no difference between "en-us" or "en-gb" for example. In order to get the country you need to get lat/long coordinates using the GPS and use one of the online services that return the name of the country by giving these coordinates. 
Alternatively, you can also use services that return the country based on a giving IP address.